# What is below definition actually doing?

Tags: c, arrays

In one of the questions of SO, I came across below defination:

```
char randchar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" [rand() % 26];
```

I know that `rand() % 26` will give a random number from 0 to 25.
But what is actually happening in above definition? When the expression is evaluated(compile time or run time)?What will be the contain of stack.

What do we call such definitions in C.Which feature is this?

Comment: Can't you just run and see that ?

Comment: I did run it,But I wants to know what is happening behind the scenes,In terms of memory allocation and etc.(run it on online compiler)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" [rand() % 26];` is an expression which is being used as an initialized for `randchar`.

- `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` is an array of 27 `char` (26 letters and a null terminator).
- The square brackets are the array indexing operator.
- `rand()` generates a random number
- `rand() % 26` converts that to a number between `0` and `25` (inclusive)
- That result is used as the array index.
- The `char` in the array is copied to `randchar`.

It could have been written:

```
char const letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int random_number = rand() % 26;

char randchar = letters[random_number];
```

Comment: Thanks,So `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` stored on stack or in text segment?Or it is compiler specific whether to declare the string as array of const or not.

Comment: It has static storage duration and is non-modifiable.  To see what your compiler does with it you could compile the code and inspect the linker map

Comment: @Vagish Since it is literal it has to be on read-only location

Comment: @Gopi it could be in a writable location, it's just that your code can't rely on that. Some older compilers would make the strings writable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes I know it might in write-location also. But on all new systems with new compilers we see that literals are put into read-only location isn't it?

Comment: @Gopi don't know, and don't want to know either..:) In any case, you can put them where you want by giving options to the linker.

Comment: @Matt-McNabb, "is an expression which is being used as an initializer". But it is a dynamic initializer and so requires code execution (executing rand(), where you may possibly also first want to seed it). How does the compiler do that? In which C-standard are dynamic initializers allowed? Is this only allowed in functions? Can you initialize a global variable in this way?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie when it is an automatic variable, since C99 the initializer can be any expression. Static variables still need constant expression.

Answer (score 3):

The above code is equivalent to

```
char arr[]  = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char randchar = arr[rand() % 26];
```

Basically in your case, what is being done is the number generated by the `rand() % 26` expression is being used as the index of the *unnamed* array `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` to get the value of a particular element.

Answer (score 1):

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` is a C string literal. So it's an array of `char` with a terminating `NULL`.

`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[x]` is the char located at position `x` within the string, assuming `x` is within bounds and undefined otherwise.

`rand()` returns a pseudo-random number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is usually at least `0xffff` — i.e. a lot larger than 26.

`x % 26` returns `x` modulo 26.

So the full statement: obtains a random number, takes the remainder of it when divided by 26 to give a number in the range 0–25, and uses that number to look up a character in a string literal, that string literal being the uppercase English alphabet. i.e. it selects a random uppercase English language letter.